# Update multus configuration file

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following situation: I have deployed Multus CNI on a k8s cluster which was using Calico as its network plugin. Everything went fine, I was able to have multiple interfaces in my pods. Then I wanted to change something on the Calico configuration (which is the plugin used by Multus for the cluster network). I am modifying the `calico-config` ConfigMap and restart the calico pods. This is generating new Calico configuration files on the nodes (the `/etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist` file) but Multus is still using the Calico configuration that it found when Multus was installed (that configuration is embedded into the `/etc/cni/net.d/00-multus.conf` file). Is there any way to instruct Multus to update its config file? or I have to update it myself?

Thank you in advance for any help/directions on this.